# How to fire two listeners on the tablelayout by one click: tablerow and its cell

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, android-tablelayout

By using `TableLayout` I created a simple table and added `OnClick` listeners to both the table rows and the rows' individual cells. However,  touching any cell executes only the cell listener and `TableRow` listener isn't called.

How can I get both of these listeners to execute with a single touch on the table?

Or any better suggestion on such scenario?

Code:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PostSampleTable extends TableLayout {
    public PostSampleTable(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) );
        super.setClickable( true );         
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++) {
            TableRow lineRow = new TableRow( getContext() ); 
            super.addView( lineRow );
            addRowListener( lineRow, i);

            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                View cell = createTextView("DATACELLAT_" +i+ "_" +j+ "", 100);
                lineRow.addView( cell );                
                addCellListener( cell, i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addRowListener(TableRow lineRow, int i) {
        MyRowL mrl = new MyRowL() {
            int rowNum = 0;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("cxc", "CLICKED Line Row [ " +getRowNum()+ "]"); 
            }

            @Override
            public void setRowNum(int rowNum) {
                this.rowNum = rowNum;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowNum() {
                return this.rowNum;
            }
        };

        mrl.setRowNum( i );

        lineRow.setOnClickListener( mrl ); 
    }

    private void addCellListener(View cell, int i, int j) {
        MyCellL mcl = new MyCellL() {           
            int rowNum = 0;
            int colNum = 0; 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("cxc", "CLICKED the cell [ " +getRowNum()+ ", " + getColNum()+ "]"); 
            }

            @Override
            public void setRowNum(int rowNum) {
                this.rowNum = rowNum;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowNum() {
                return this.rowNum;
            }

            @Override
            public void setColNum(int colNum) {
                this.colNum = colNum;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColNum() {
                return this.colNum;
            }
        };

        mcl.setRowNum( i );
        mcl.setColNum( j );

        cell.setOnClickListener( mcl ); 
    }

    private TextView createTextView(String text, int  width) {
        TextView reply = new TextView( getContext() );
        reply.setText(text); 
        reply.setWidth( width );
        return reply ;
    }

    interface MyRowL extends OnClickListener {
        public void setRowNum(int rowNum);
        public int getRowNum();         
    }

    interface MyCellL extends MyRowL {
        public void setColNum(int colNum);
        public int getColNum();         
    } 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fire two listeners for tablelayout: tablerow and its cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947027/how-to-fire-two-listeners-for-tablelayout-tablerow-and-its-cells)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to fire the `TableRow` `OnClickListener()` directly at the end of the cell `onClick()`:

Using your cell `onClick()` as an example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("cxc", "CLICKED the cell [ " +getRowNum()+ ", " + getColNum()+ "]"); 

    ((TableRow)v.getParent()).performClick();
}
```

If a cell gets clicked, both `onClickListner()` methods are called.  Also, if a row is clicked directly, say because it is missing cells, only the row `onClickListener()` will be called.

If you are only targeting devices of API 15 onwards there is also and alternative method to `performClick()`, called [`callOnClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#callOnClick%28%29).